# Is there any major programming language that doesn't support any form of reflection?

Tags: c, reflection, programming-languages

Wikipedia defines reflection as follows:

> In computer science, reflection is the process by which a computer
>   program can observe (do type introspection) and modify its own
>   structure and behavior at runtime.[1]

Is there any major programming language (widely used in Academia or Industry) that doesn't support any form of reflection? All the examples I'm currently thinking of have at least limited support. But for C I'm for example not sure.

Comment: I would think that most of the traditional procedural programming languages, e.g. BASIC, FORTRAN, C, Pascal, Modula-2, Ada, COBOL, etc, lack reflection ?

Comment: I think that this is an issue of interpreted program vs compiled

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch. Though a well-intentioned question, this one looks to me like it's going to produce a long list of "I thought of another one" answers, which isn't really appropriate for this site. Voting to close.

Comment: I'd also throw in Forth.

Comment: @user384706: no, the limitation comes from the language design, not whether it's compiled or interpreted. Sometimes a particular implementation may have means to overcome the design limitations. I'd say, if your C compiler (and OS) lets your C program access all its memory (data and code) and the CPU registers that the program operates with (maybe with `setjmp()/longjmp()`), reflection becomes a mere exercise in low level coding for a particular platform. It doesn't have to be easy, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C, C++ dont have any forms of reflection. What can be done is embed debugging symbol in the executable with the compiler, and then process the symbol table from within the executable. However, this process must be implemented by the code (i.e. write code in c to break down and process the symbol table in the executable). Therefore, it isn't inherent in the language.

Comment: C++ has typeof and dynamic_cast.

Comment: GNU C implementation also support "typeof". It's a primitive kind of reflection, but it's something you can start with to make some interesting solutions.

Comment: C++ does *not* have `typeof`, but does have `decltype` (which is quite similar g++ `typeof` extension).

Comment: typeof isnt actual reflection. I.e. it isnt evaluated at runtime rather compile time.

Comment: Maybe @frast meant typeid. In any case, the OPs definition says "modify its own structure" which C++ can't do. That's a fairly strict definition of reflection. I think most people would say "observe" counts as a form of reflection, albeit restricted.

Comment: @smparkes yea, thats the closest that you can get in C++. However, this is still a far cry from C# or Java where you can get the class' name and instantiate by name. (Although you could create a table to do this, it would be extremely painful and unmaintainable)

Comment: +1 C definitely does not have reflection of any sort.

Comment: @smparkes: You are right. I meant typeid. I do not use these features often. In C++ it is seen as a bad smell to use this. A double dispatch solution is used to achieve the sort of things you can do with reflection.

Comment: @chacham15: Having done it in production, I can say the table isn't _that_ painful or hard to maintain. You don't create a table in one place but instead create static singleton metadata objects per class that register themselves with a directory. Not saying it's great, but it can be made to work.

Comment: @smparkes The one reflection feature that I cannot figure out how to hack without diving into assembly code is calling a random function. What i mean is: given a function pointer, the number of arguments the function takes (as an int), and a list of arguments, call the function pointer with those arguments. Currently, i have a long list of: `if (argcount == 1) (*ptr)(arg[0]) else if (argcount == 2)...` which gets it done for most common cases, but it cant expand arbitrarily.

Comment: @chacham15: yeah, I haven't even gone that far. I stopped at being able to call a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

COBOL is a major language that does not.  Nor any of the HDLs (VHDL, Verilog, ...).

I think a more interesting question is, what languages have *complete* access to their structure by "reflection"? (e.g, "what in this expression?" "What's the type of that expression?" "Build me a new class.", etc.)  AFAIK, only LISP meets this requirement.  Other languages provide some reflection at best but cannot entirely manipulate those langauges.

That leaves the question as to why one would add only partial reflection to a language.  We make our languages Turing capable so that if we want to code something, we're pretty sure we can code it in our language.  Why aren't our languages correspondingly "full reflection" capable?

One way out of this is to use [program transformation systems (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), which are tools designed to manipulate code.  A truly generic PTS (such as Stratego, DMS or TXL) can manipulate arbitrary programs in arbitrary way, providing what amounts to "full reflection". This allows one to do metaprogramming on arbitrary languages; you don't have to depend on your language committee or your compiler vendor to add bits and pieces of reflection capability.

Comment: Javascript is also extremely reflective, in some ways more than Lisp (eg you can get the source text of a function after it's been defined).

Comment: Lisp gives you access to its content as easily interpreted structures (S-expressions, isomorphic to ASTs).   JavaScript may give you back the source text of a function, but that isn't very helpful: now all you need is a full JavaScript parser/name resolver to figure out what you got.  If you are willing to go that far, any language which will give you access to the source file from which it is compiled is equally good, and IMHO equally useless; the point of reflection is access in terms of the language elements and concepts, not text.

Comment: JavaScript also has `eval`, so you could get the source of a function, munge it a bit, and `eval` a new function based on it. I agree S-expressions have better *usability* (the mapping of language elements to values is more direct), but I think JavaScript reflection is equally powerful.

Comment: The point is that you want access to the language in terms of its elements and structures.  If you are handed text, you have no access you didn't have when all you had was the raw text file.  I don't see how eval helps; where does it let me shred a JavaScript function into its various scopes, etc.?